# send uploaded files and inputs values with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to upload files with datas using ajax.
here is my html form :

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="name" value="test" />
  <input type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*" />
  <input id = "submit" type="submit" />
</body>
```

when I send the uploaded file alone with ajax it is working using new FormData();

```
var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files');   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
alert(form_data);                             
$.ajax({
            url: 'test.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response); 
            }
 });
```

but Idon't know how to send the input 'name' with Data

```
var DATA = 'name='+name;

$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "post",
  data: DATA,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log($response);             
  },
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You say "I don't know how to send the input 'name' with Data" but then you show an example of exactly how to do it, or so it appears. What's the problem, _exactly_?